# Excel VBA Worksheet_Change refer to cells in another sheet with named range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use a user's input from a dropdown (yes/no) in sheet1 to hide/unhide rows in sheet2. A formula in sheet2 refers to the input in sheet1.

I also think that a named range (scope: workbook) on its own can only refer to the same sheet? Code below does not work but illustrates. Could not make other references work to named ranges with `ThisWorkbook` or similar.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("screener")) Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2")
            .Range("calc1.1").Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = (.Range("calc1.1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "No")
            .Range("calc1.2").Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = (.Range("calc1.2").Cells(1, 1).Value = "No")
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In a worksheet code module, any reference to  `Range` or `Cells` that doesn't specify a sheet will refer to the sheet containing the code. You need to alter the unqualified `Range("calc1.1")` to specify the sheet (same with Calc1.2)

Comment: I saw that, but modify how? Like so `.Range`?

Comment: Yes, just like you did the other two instances.

Comment: Unfortunately, does not hide any rows. But also no error message.

Comment: Step through the code and see what's happening. We can't debug it for you if there aren't any errors.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to "step through", seems to me the event is not triggered - what I hear though is that the code should work?

Comment: @Rico To step through, first use a Breakpoint (F9) or `Stop` command, trigger the code so that it halts at the breakpoint, then use F8 to step through 1 line at a time or F5 to run to end

Comment: Rico, where is this code entered? In a module? Or behind a sheet?

Comment: @CLR a good question: I double-clicked on the sheet in the tree, so should be behind sheet 1.

Comment: I found the first problem: `Application.EnableEvents` has magically turned itself to false. Now there's a runtime error 9: subscript out of range.

Comment: Solved: needs the actual sheet name.